# How to Compare two strings in anular.js view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two ng-repeat elements where I want to display data only when the text value of both the array element matches. I tried using ng-show but it doest not terminate the condition when the value matches.

```
<div ng-show="activity.id == actor"> found
    <span ng-repeat="text in activity.text">
        \{{text}}
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by *`when the text value of both the array element matches`*? do you wanted to compare each and every element of array?

Comment: let's take this example: I have ["One", "two", "three"] in actors aaray. In activities array I have ["two", ''nine","seven", "One"]. While iterating over first array I get "One" and if I find "One" then only it should print \\{text}} value. I hope it is clear to you now. @PankajParkar

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div ng-if="activity.id === 'actor' && propertyFromSecond.ngrepeat ==='actor'">
```

Use ng-show if you need to hide or show information depending on situation
Use ng-if if you sure you always want to render data that meets the condition. Elements inside of ng-if don't get into DOM if condition is not met.